# How do you delete every line but those starting with one of several specific words? bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I am looking for a command that will allow me to strip everything from a variable but lines starting with one of several specific words.

I have looked at many a sed command but I simply cannot solve the issue. Either I am returned a ! instead of the first character in the wanted word and simply the last character deleted from the (in this case single) other line.

The following is merely an example of what I have tried - meaning that I do not seek alternatives to the method itself. Only how to clean the variable from everything but the given lines!

```
distro_raw="lsb_release -si"
distro=`echo $distro_raw | sed -r '/ubuntu/!d'`
```

I have tried other ways (not using -r but rather '/s//g' as well). I am merely trying to exemplify what I want with code. It is obviously wrong but may make the problem more clear.

EDIT:

A more clear example:

```
server_file=`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`
server`echo $server_file | sed ${what_to_write_before}deb${what_to_write_after}`
```

which will then delete everything but the line starting with "server". What I do not know is what to sorround the word "deb" - so that the command only returns the lines starting with "deb"

Example input:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release amd64 (20141022.2)]/ utopic main restricted

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release amd64 (20141022.2)]/ utopic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
```

The wanted output is

```
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide an exemple of input and the expected output? As i understand it, grep would do the trick `distro=$(echo $distro_raw | grep ubuntu)`

Comment: @Alfwed, not without more quotes. As it is, the `echo` will combine everything onto one line, because it's being passed one argument per word, not the entire string as a single argument with whitespace/newlines intact.

Comment: where did the first 2 lines of your expected output come from???

Comment: That is a very good question Ed - they seemed to have disappeared. Strange as I copied them from the very same text a few lines above. Something I have done or some bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't capture the file's contents and set up a pipeline -- just point `grep` (or `sed`, or `awk`, or any other text processing tool that can filter with a regex) directly against your file, using `^` to anchor your regex to the front of the line:

```
result=$(grep -E '^deb' </etc/apt/sources.list)
```

Now, if you had more words than just "deb", an alternation would be appropriate:

```
result=$(grep -E '^(deb|foo|bar)' </etc/apt/sources.list)
```

That said, if you want all non-comment content from the file, I wouldn't do it that way at all: Just filter out the comments and blank lines (including lines which are blank after removing comments):

```
sed -e 's/#.*//' </etc/apt/sources.list | grep -E -v '^[[:space:]]*'
```

Finally, for your amusement, here's an approach in pure bash that really does extract only server names, rather than putting whole lines into a variable named `server`, and filters them for uniqueness:

```
# Collect server URLs into an associative array
declare -A servers=( )
while read -r; do
  line=${REPLY%%#*}
  [[ $line ]] || continue
  read -r type url repos <<<"$line"
  echo "Found a line of type $type with url $url for repos $repos" >&2
  servers["$url"]=$repos
done </etc/apt/sources.list

# Iterate over the servers we found:
for server in "${!servers[@]}"; do
  echo "$server"
done
```

Comment: Ight I will trust the masses of those more capable than I at this and mark this answer as the solution - more for the sake of others who might be reading it. 

Regarding using echo - i did try both :-) But regardless. 

Thank you for the thorough reply! Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Reading title of question

```
sed -n '/^one\|^two\|^three/p' file
```

will keep lines starting with one or two or three

```
sed '/^one\|^two\|^three/d' file
```

will delete lines starting with those words

Comment: Aha! Now this works. How would you go about keeping the output of the sed on separate lines as well? As it is the lines merge into a single line from what I can gather.

Comment: You have wonderful example input of sources.lst, we need also expected output to see

Comment: well if i undrestand correctly, you can do piping like this: sed -n '/^one\|^two/{p;p}' file | sed 's/abc/def/' where p is print. You will make copies in files. Then you can substitute one of them. as i noticed removing -updates is goal?

Comment: or better make substitution inside like sed -n '/^one\|^two/{p;s/abc/def/;p}

Comment: @cxou, it's the `echo $var` (vs `echo "$var"`) that makes them merge. Fix your quotes and that won't happen -- or just read direct from the file.

Comment: Thank you! As I said what I stated was merely an example - what I am trying to do entails to much for a stackoverflow question :-)

@CharlesDuffy thank you for the tip :-)

Thanks for all of your input! It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @cxou, ...that said, I _do_ believe my answer (preceding this one slightly) included something with all the functionality of this one (the `grep -E '^(deb|foo|bar)'` example, which filters for lines starting with `deb`, `foo` or `bar`), so I'd appreciate some guidance on how I could have made it more clear/useful.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy for effort +1

Comment: Certainly! As stated the examples were merely examples - as such I was trying to figure out how do what I was specifcally asking. Not solving the given examples smarter.. As such - the answer to the main question (the title) gave me what I needed more :-)

I cannot say why - but the commands (all three) you gave did not work as well as the examples josifoski gave. 

As such all I can tell you I guess is - thank you for the thorough answer. It taught me a lot. But what answered my question was this one. Sometimes simple is better...
Again I learnt more from your answer - just not what I needed!

Comment: Why on earth would you use sed for this? It's PRECISELY the job grep was invented to do - `g/re/p` get it? @CharlesDuffy has exactly the right answer with `grep -E '^(deb|foo|bar)'`, hence the many upvotes his answer has vs all the other answers.

Comment: clear maestro :) for speedyness via command line for parsing txt files it could be that gawk is better than python or ruby

Comment: @cxou, heh. I'd be curious, if we had the opportunity, to figure out _why_ those examples didn't work for you -- I wonder if maybe you tested them then ran `echo $result` rather than `echo "$result"`? -- but that's hardly a conversation to carry on in the comments of someone else's answer. :)

Comment: I feel a little bad about the turn of events -- this answer may not be ideal, but also isn't wrong outright, and at least deserves an upvote; as such, it has my +1. (That said, one caveat -- treating `\|` as an alternation is a GNU extension; the POSIX specification doesn't require it in BRE).

Comment: I would like to vote it up but sadly I do not have enough points on this end of StackExchange... josifoski - thank you for your answer. But I am - by others superior to me in the field of bash - being told I am doing something outright wrong by selecting your answer as the solution. This must mean I made an unclear explanation. To avoid making other readers of this question unclear I deem it necessary to mark Charles answer as the solution - even though yours came closer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example you supplied in your question, this could be as simple as

```
sed '/ubuntu/!d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Example output:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
...
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: Leaving in comments is contrary to desired behavior -- hence "starting with" as part of the spec.